# rlimit64 integer overflow

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I'm currently trying to limit the memory resources of the process. Before to do so, I prepare the `rlimit64` structure calling `getrlimit64`. When compiling the following code

```
    rlimit64 as_limit;
    if (getrlimit64(RLIMIT_AS, &as_limit) == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << as_limit.rlim_cur << std::endl;
        std::cerr << as_limit.rlim_max << std::endl;

        as_limit.rlim_cur = 0x040000000 * 16;

        std::cerr << as_limit.rlim_cur << std::endl;
        std::cerr << as_limit.rlim_max << std::endl;
    }
```

I'm getting a warning about integer overflow for the line with an assigment of `as_limit.rlim_cur`. Hovever, as an output I get:

```
    18446744073709551615
    18446744073709551615
    0
    18446744073709551615
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hex literal is being interpretted as an int.

Try using:

```
0x040000000LL * 16;
```

So that the compiler treats the literal as a long long.

Since a long long literal (the LL suffix) is C99, you're likely better off casting to whatever the type of the struct member is (though I would imagine any recent compiler would have support for LL -- gcc definitely does).  For example, you could cast to long long.